# What's the difference between a XIB and a NIB file?

Tags: iphone

What's the difference between a XIB and a NIB file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

XIB is actually XML file. NIB is binary. So there are problems when using SVN with NIB files. So XIB replaces them.

Comment: There aren't really problems, it's just a lot less efficient since you can't do diffs and have to treat them as a binary file (like any image checked into SVN or some other SCM).

The ability to diff is also helpful to understood what you have changed.

Comment: Inability of diff isn't a problem? What if multiple people work on the same file? If it's not a problem, then I have noting to say :-)

Answer (score 2):

XIB is pronounced "nib".

A XIB file is XML.
A NIB file is binary.

XIBs replaced NIBs.

There really isn't a difference between how they are used, but XIBs are now the standard while developing. I believe that XIBs are translated into NIBs when the application is compiled. They are both used the same way and are both edited in Interface Builder.

For more information about what a XIB is look [here](http://speirs.org/blog/2007/12/5/what-are-xib-files.html).

If you need more information you can find a ton of information about this subject if you use google.

Comment: Unfortunately, that link is dead and it isn't even on web.archive.org. However, there appears to be a copy here: https://titanwolf.org/Network/Articles/Article?AID=50c99262-8642-4d23-ae64-7dff803ffcbb

Answer (score 0):

Nothing (as of now).  Files with the .xib extension are pronounced "nib" files.

Check out the [wikipedia article here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_Builder) for a more in-depth explanation.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://www.cocoarocket.com/articles/xibnib.html)

Basically:

- **XIB**: Text-based XML
- **NIB**: Archives, created by Xcode.